# Forcing voltage drop on computer PSU

Tags: power-supply, voltage

It may sound weird, but bear with me.

As part of a research project, I need to force a modern computer power supply (not any brand/model in particular; the more general the solution, the better) to drop the output voltage. Not drop completely to 0 V, of course, but drop enough to affect the computer's operation.

Now, I understand that the problem is that the main job of a PSU is to provide a stable voltage to the computer, and from my initial experiment, they are very good at it.

So the question is the following:

Given complete control over the input of the PSU (suppose I have a device in series with the PSU, and I can control both AC voltage and current that the PSU receives), how can I force the PSU to generate a sub-nominal output voltage on any of the power cables?

I can't modify or bypass the PSU and I can't place anything between the PSU and the computer. Suppose the case is closed and I can't open it to access anything.

The project goal is to modify the "grid" power in some way such that a programm on the computer can detect that something changed.
This is not trivial because the PSU does not communicate power quality information ot the motherboard.
It already works when generating DC voltage drop (bypassing the PSU) and reading sensor values but now it needs to work from outside the PSU.

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: You're going to have to redesign the power supply to add this feature you need. It's not something built in, so unless you add it you won't have it.

Comment: You might want to explain what would be the purpose of this, but it is unlikely to cause any power dips on an unmodified comouter. It would do a total reset of the computer if PSU cannot provide the required output, or it will ignore the dip if PSU can provide the required output.

Comment: @Agriseld What are you expecting to get out of this experiment? The short answer is if you manipulate the voltages enough, at best, the computer undergoes POR with a PS error log. And at worst, you destroy the computer by running it with non-compliant voltage transients.

Comment: Gonna need a hammer.

Answer (score 5):

Usually impossible. If you give the computer power supply too low AC in, it will likely shut down rather than output sub-nominal output voltages.

It will also signal the motherboard when outputs are sub-nominal and the motherboard uses that as a reset.

So you need a better way than to control the AC into the power supply.

If the point is to trigger a standard computer supply, then it can become hard to modify it.

If the point is to give a motherboard sub-nominal voltages, then you don't need the computer power supply to do that.

In many places inside the computer, the voltages from the power supply are not used directly, but through switch mode voltage regulators, so it might be that small glitches on the motherboard input will still not affect the regulator outputs much.

Comment: No sadly I cannot modify or bypass the PSU, I need to go through it and affect the computer.
Do you have more info on the sub-nominal trigger sent to the motherboard? I could not find a sensor accessible to the OS that detects input power quality, but an alarm signal is very interesting for my project.

Comment: It looks like you need to read how computer power supplies work. There is a specification for it. If you can't modify the PSU then you likely can't trigger unstable voltages without the motherboard getting a reset signal or the power supply shutting down. At least for any generic solution. It's not an alarm, I guess you could call it an emergency stop.

Comment: @Agriseld Most motherboards have voltage sensors of their own measuring the voltages of the major power rails (CPU Vcore, +3.3V, +5V, +12V, etc.). These sensors are readily available to the OS and applications. But the PSU itself (if we're talking about plain dumb ATX PSUs, not proprietary server gear) does not do any "quality reporting". All that ATX has is a single "Power Good" signal (one wire going to the motherboard). If the PSU detects voltages going out of spec, it will turn this signal off, directly triggering a reset.